# How to encrypt/decrypt the url in J2ME app?

Tags: url, java-me, encryption

My application need to connect to critical data on our server, and i want to encrypt the link to the server, so, How could I do that?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: did you check how they do it in Java SE? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123976/url-encryption-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [bouncy castle library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) for encrypt and decrypt. For more information look this article, [How to encrypt / decrypt with AES from Bouncy Castle API in J2ME applications.](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/12/28/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-with-aes-from-bouncy-castle-api-in-j2me-applications/)

Also look this discussion on Nokia fourm, [Data encryption/decryption in J2ME.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?80700-Data-encryption-decryption-in-J2ME)