# How to generate a 48 character Hash using SHA384 in Java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, hash, spring-security

i'm trying to generate a 48 character hash string in Java using `SHA384`, the output should look something like this:

> PÊ&¿ a»@óæS0iÛ6në0Ê`o€X·„\KÃò¢ï¼fÖ…)nE@ó^s

My current implementation is as follows:

```
public static String getHash(byte[] inputBytes, String algorithm) throws Exception{
    String hashValue = "";
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        messageDigest.update(inputBytes);
        byte[] digestedBytes = messageDigest.digest();
        hashValue = 
        DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(digestedBytes).toLowerCase();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hashValue;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getHash("The quick brown fox Jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes(), "SHA-384"));
}
```

Output:

> b94a2179d90daf662f2ae8e41f92c2831eb0eea5a352f81ac7b0a80a07b2c357d88d0e3fc12bf4f0d888335508b09c41

As observed, the output string is a 96 Character string instead of 48, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you converted `digestedBytes` to hex. Note that `digestedBytes.length` equals 48 (I tested). But your "final" string has 64 bytes (but only 42 characters in UTF-8)... so there's some mismatch, either your final string is wrong or you actually want 64-byte hashes.

Comment: Use UUIID generator

Comment: Thank @SumeshTG ,  I checked for the length as well, its showing 48, do both of you mind helping with code examples?

Comment: @pkpnd please refer to my last comment.

Comment: @pkpnd when i try to print bytes to the console it brings this string "[B@6659c656" is there any other suggested type other than hex that i could use to actually get the actual 48 character string?

Comment: @ThulaniTembo How are you supposed to convert bytes to characters? If using UTF-8 encoding, many bytes correspond to unprintable characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
public class Main {
    public static String getHash(byte[] inputBytes, String algorithm) throws Exception{
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
            messageDigest.update(inputBytes);
            byte[] digestedBytes = messageDigest.digest();
            return new String(digestedBytes, "UTF-8");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(getHash("The quick brown fox Jumps over the lazy dog".getBytes(), "SHA-384"));
    }
}
```

This converts your 48 byte array into a String using the UTF-8 encoding. However, not all bytes represent printable characters, so you'll end up with a String with slightly fewer characters.

Comment: Amazing!! This works like magic! as you mentioned it does chunk out some byte unless is use ASCII as the charset, it brings all the 48 characters....Thank You so much you just literally saved my Job! Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.journaldev.examples;

import java.util.UUID;
/**
 * Java UUID randomUUID Example
 *
 */
public class UUIDExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialize uuid
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        System.out.println(uuid);

    }

}
```

Try this for generating random id's

Comment: thanks but i'm  thinking that maybe I was clear in my question, what i'm trying to do is to get a certain string and then Hash it with SHA384, in the specifications that were given to me, i'm expected to produce a 48 Character hash string, i've tried the method above but i'm ending up with a 96 character hash, how do I atleast limit it to 48 characters output!

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood.Do some google for encryption and decryption.

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123976/url-encryption-in-java